# Geomarker Scaling

Tags: geography, geodesy

Struggling to get a 3d cylinder to scale properly on a street map.  I want to use the stacked cylinder as a custom pin.

```
mypin = Graphics3D[
Table[Cylinder[{{0, 0, h}, {0, 0, h + 0.95}}, 0.25], {h, 1, 19}], 
ImageSize -> Automatic];

GeoGraphics[{GeoPosition[{51.5144, -0.08028}], 
GeoMarker[GeoPosition[{51.5144, -0.08028}], mypin, 
"Scale" -> Automatic, "Alignment" -> Bottom]}, 
GeoRange -> Quantity[0.05, "Miles"]]
```

I know automatic doesn't work on its own but I've been replacing it with various values and all that happens is the marker vanishes.

I should add that the reason for doing this is that the cylinder represents a building of x floors, and once I get the cylinder scaled properly the intention is to use each cylinder to display various feature of the building.  E.g. Red cylinder if a floor is over capacity, cylinder radius proportional to the number of desks it contains.

Comment: Tried "Scale" -> Scaled[.1]` or `"Scale" -> Offset[30]`?

Comment: @kguler - yes that would have been it alright.  Still learning.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mypin1 = Graphics3D[Table[{If[h > 14, Red, LightBlue],
   Cylinder[{{0, 0, h}, {0, 0, h + 0.95}}, 1]}, {h, 1, 19}], Boxed -> False]

mypin2 = Graphics3D[
   Table[Cylinder[{{0, 0, h}, {0, 0, h + 0.95}}, 1], {h, 1, 9}], Boxed -> False];



GeoGraphics[
 {
  GeoPosition[{51.5144, -0.08028}],

  GeoMarker[
   GeoPosition[{51.5144, -0.08028}],
   mypin1,
   "Scale" -> Scaled[0.3],
   "Alignment" -> Bottom],

  GeoMarker[
   GeoPosition[{51.5144, -0.08028}],
   Style[Text["5 floors too much!"], Bold, Red, 16],
   "Scale" -> Scaled[0.3],
   "Alignment" -> Top],

  GeoMarker[
   GeoPosition[{51.51445, -0.08}],
   mypin2,
   "Scale" -> Scaled[0.15],
   "Alignment" -> Bottom]
  },
 GeoRange -> Quantity[0.05, "Miles"]]
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect answer thank you.  I wasn't aware of being able to "Scale" using Scaled, and I particularly liked the extension to solving the whole problem.